# NixOS: Setting options for nix-shell

Tags: nixos

Is it possible to set Options (http://nixos.org/nixos/options.html) just for a single nix-shell instead of defining them globally at `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix`?

Comment: This is a question for [superuser](http://superuser.com/) I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those options you are referring to are only meant for NixOS, which usually translate (in the background) to configuring systemd unit files and creating configurations files in `/etc`.

On the other hand, the `nix-shell` tool is part of Nix (the package manager) which can be used on any Linux distribution (alongside any other package manager),  and also on the latest macOS / OS X.

Nix (the package manager) only installs binary packages, and does not configure them, like other linux package managers do. Something like how  homebrew works.

To recap:

- NixOS (`nixos-*`) commands use Nix to install **and** to configure binaries of packages.
- Nix (`nix-*`) commands **only** install binaries of packages; you have to configure them yourself.

If you are running NixOS or any systemd-based Linux distro, there is a way to create systemd containers using the same NixOS options. Documentation on containers is avaliable [here](http://nixos.org/nixos/manual/index.html#ch-containers).

Now, before you start jumping into containers with Nix, please know that the `nixos-container` command is still a work in progress, and requires some knowledge of the [Nix expression language](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/index.html). Nonetheless, any feedback is more than welcome, and Nix developers are actively working on improving it.

If you are only looking to configure certain packages (eg. Vim, weechat) to be used across you system, this is also possible for some of them, but currently also requires some knowledge of the [Nix expression language](https://nixos.org/manual/nix/stable/language/index.html). Let me know which packages you are interested in to configure, and I can tell you how hard it would be to do it.

Hope this helps you a bit.

Comment: It seems like it should possible to execute nixos-container within a nix-shell and assuming you're on nixos, this should be able to create the container. It may also be possible to bring in docker in a nix-shell, and launch a docker container inside a nix-shell. I haven't worked out a workflow for isolated service development though.